# Uncaught TypeError: text.search is not a function at HTMLLIElement

Tags: javascript, java, html

So I'm trying to prevent certain word's from being used in a text box on my site. I keep getting the console error Uncaught TypeError: text.search is not a function at HTMLLIElement though.

Here is the code im using:

```js
window.onload=function(){
var banned = ['MMM','XXX'];
document.getElementById('field_1_17').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('field_1_17').value;
    for (var x=0;x<banned.length;x++) {
        if (text.search(banned[x]) !== -1) {
            alert(banned[x]+' is not allowed!');
        }
        var regExp = new RegExp(banned[x]);
        text = text.replace(regExp,'');
    }
    document.getElementById('field_1_17').value = text;
},false);
}
```

Here is the element/textbox in question:

```html
<input name="input_17" id="input_1_17" type="text" value="death" class="medium" maxlength="12" tabindex="5" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" data-emoji_font="true" style="font-family: Radnika, sans-serif, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;, Symbola, EmojiSymbols !important;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to update the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        var banned = ['MMM','XXX'];
        document.getElementById('input_1_17').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            var text = document.getElementById('input_1_17').value;
            for (var x=0;x<banned.length;x++) {
                if (text.search(banned[x]) !== -1) {
                    alert(banned[x]+' is not allowed!');
                }
                var regExp = new RegExp(banned[x]);
                text = text.replace(regExp,'');
            }
            document.getElementById('input_1_17').value = text;
        },false);
    }
</script>
```

Because your input tag id is input_1_17 and you are using field_1_17 so updated this.
If you want, you can change input tag id only , you can assign id field_1_17 in that case no need to change anything in your script

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. Such a silly mistake. Thank you thank you